# Can we export data from hadoop to csv using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I try to read spec from sqoop and there is no solution right now about how to export to csv format using sqoop?
is it possible if we want ti export data from hadoop to csv using sqoop?
is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sqoop to copy data from Hadoop to local filesystem using Sqoop. Sqoop strictly works with importing/exporting data to/from RDBMS (using JDBC).

Rather, you could just copy the data from Hadoop to local filesystem using hadoop command line tool `hadoop fs -get [hadoop_src] [local_dest]`.